# Can you eventually close an opensource program?

Tags: open-source

I am slowly starting to build myself a small game engine using openGL and C++ and I thought it would be kinda nice to make it open source for the time being, problem is that I may want to eventually market it once I add in more unique or detailed features. I know most licenses for open source software state that future versions must also be open source, but given that it would be my program, would I be allowed to eventually stop making it open source?

Comment: The reason I ask a question about open source on here is I would assume quite a few programmers would have experience helping out a few open source projects.

Comment: If you are the copyright holder, you can do what you want. You can't however change the license of existing code (read as publicly distributed code), but no problem with new code.

Comment: My plan was to start a new version, like maybe 1.0 would be open source, but then as of 2.0 it would be closed, and for as long as I keep 2.0 and later versions going, I would still allow people to download 1.0 and source.

Comment: That is fine AFAIK. Keep v1 open and have a closed system for v2. As I said, if you are the copyright holder of the code, it is your choice. Just remember licensing requirements of any dependent libraries or code you are using. THAT might limit what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Depend on the Open Source License you use and the way you set up your project. You could use the BSD/MIT licence and then you don't have the viral problem of the GPL/LGPL (but not the advantages either). You can also leave your main engine Open & Free and just sell your unique features.

There is many ways!

Comment: Only other people's code under GPL can infect your code. Your own code cant infect itself under any license.